# Pytorch operations (adding and average) between layers

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch, runtime-error

I am building a pytorch nn model that uses skip connections between two parallel sequential layers. This model is known as the merge-and-run. I will include an image of the model as given by the paper publication.
[merge-and-run model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNarh.png)
You can look it up in the literature for more reference on how it works. The thing I'm having problem with is the operation of adding and dividing skip connections from the output of one layer to a point farther down the line in the model. One of the operations involve in these skip connections is an addition. I am doing this addition using the following code:

```
def forward(self, x):
    x = self.relu1(self.conv1(x))
    print("X size: ", x.size())
    av0 = (x + x)/2

    b1 = self.block1_up(av0)
    b2 = self.block1_up(av0)
    
    print("av0 size: ", av0.size())
    print("b1 size: ", b1.size())
    add1 = b1 + av0
    add2 = b2 + av0
```

The print statements project respectively the following:

```
X size:  torch.Size([128, 64, 32, 32])
av0 size:  torch.Size([128, 64, 32, 32])
b1 size:  torch.Size([128, 128, 1, 1])
```

But when calculating "add1" I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (128) must match the size of tensor b (64) at non-singleton dimension 1
```

I have tried changing the dimensions of av0 so it can fit with b1 using the view() function torch provides, but this didn't help all that much. Any help with this type of problem?

Thank you.

Comment: you can only add two tensors with the exact same shape (in your case they are two tensors that are parallel in the your architecture) but av0 and b1 have not the same shape. You would have to post more code, ie whats in block1_up?

Comment: the block1_up just has some other layers. In the paper publication they explain more (also, see the image attached). So I got the part the addition can't happen because av0 and b1 are not the same shape. the question was, how can I make them the av0 the same shape as b1?

Comment: you need to implement block1_up so that it produces the same shape as av0 or av0 the same shape as b1/b2. You should acutally not reshape anything. but I cant help you since there is missing lots of code

Comment: Thats the thing, I need block1 to stay the same. Its part of the model. Why do you say I shouldn't reshape anything?

Comment: @AngelOrtiz What you're trying to do isn't well defined. The shapes of two tensors need to be [broadcastable](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/ufuncs.html#broadcasting) in order to apply arithmetic operators (pytorch uses the same broadcasting rules as numpy). In your case the problem is that `[128, 64, 32, 32]` and `[128, 128,  1, 1]` are not broadcastable because they disagree in a non-unitary dimension (particularly 64 does not equal 128). Conceptually it's not clear what you would expect the sum of a 64 dimensional vector and a 128 dimensional vector to produce.